# PHP Header - Location Redirect seems to lose caching

Tags: php, caching, browser, redirect, header

I'm doing some cURL checks on response codes of files before redirecting requests to different hosts (to make sure the files exist before I redirect).

When we're all happy, I send them off-server to remote host and we're all happy.

The only problem seems to be it's not caching on the user's machine. Is there something I can do to let the user browser know this is the same file? I thought it would inherently know as it's just a header location redirect (i.e. header('location:http://www.locationtogo.com/asda?242');

Thanks for any help!

------- UPDATE ----------

Seems to be quite a few questions on this; so let me explain step by step...

1. User requests file from handler.php
2. handler.php does cURL check to see if response code is
3. if response code is 200 I was redirecting to the file
4. however each time reloaded the handler.php for the same file... it would reload the entire file

I've now realised - stupid mistake - but will list here just incase anyone experiences the same - I was of course, looking for response 200, not 200 or 304.

This is now caching.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. What is not caching where  and what is happening instead?

Comment: Please re-read your question. for me especially the last part is unclear. Who caches what and what not? What should be cached? What should not be cached? What is the same (it sounds as if it is not the same)?

Comment: I have now sorted this - it was my own mistake. I hope that's also cleared the step-by-step up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header along with the redirect to indicate that it can be cached.

Example (this will allow the browser to cache the response for an hour)

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600')
```

Comment: PHP/Apache Still will not cache the file unless you return the 304 yourself.

Comment: PHP/Apache does not need to (and can't) cache the file. The browser is redirected to the location and will download the file itself. Apache/PHP will never read the file (unless of course the file being redirected to is one the same server).

Answer (score -1):

PHP and apache will not cache a PHP file by default.  I recently ran into this myself. You can however return a 304 if you want and that will fix the problem.  I did it with etags.

Simply send the browser the first time an etag hash the first time it visits it.

```
header('Etag: '.$eTagHash);
```

Then, check to see if the etag is there, if so tell the browser it's a 304 not modified.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
    if(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) == trim($eTagHash)){
       header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
       exit;
    }}
```

You can set the $eTagHash to anything you want.  You should have etags enabled on the apache server as well (most do).

If you ever need to redirect somewhere else, just change the etag hash and when it doesnt match you can send the browser the header etag again with the new value.

Comment: This applies to caching the output of scripts. Not redirects. A 302 status code is required for the redirect.

Comment: That presumes he wants to send a 302 code.   He explains that the file is not cached.  To me this sounds like he is using an HTML file to redirect not the headers.  If he's using the headers cache would never be an issue because the server redirect is in the response header not in the HTML body so the question would be completely invalid anyhow.  Clearly he's asking about "cache" of the browser.

Comment: He is using a header redirect as stated in the question " I thought it would inherently know as it's just a header location redirect (i.e. header('location:http://www.locationtogo.com/asda?242');"